# Select data from MySQL table using JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to get the value passed through `pass` button in the code below, use it to select some specified data from a MySQL table and display it.

Actually, this is an event calendar. When someone clicks on a day, I want to pop up a model box and display the events related to that day.

Please help me. It is for my university final year project.

```
<?php
$dayCount = 1;
for ($cb = 1; $cb <= $boxDisplay; $cb++) {
    if (($cb >= $currentMonthFirstDay+1 || $currentMonthFirstDay == 7) && $cb <= ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay)) {
        // Current date
        $currentDate = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-'.$dayCount;
        $eventNum = 0;

        // Include db configuration file
        include 'dbConfig.php';

        // Get number of events based on the current date
        $result = $db->query("SELECT title FROM events WHERE date = '".$currentDate."' AND status = 1");
        $eventNum = $result->num_rows;

        // Define date cell color
        if (strtotime($currentDate) == strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))) {
            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="grey date_cell">';
        } elseif ($eventNum > 0) {
            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="light_sky date_cell">';
        } else {
            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="date_cell">';
        }

        // Date cell
        echo '<span>';
        echo $dayCount;
        echo '</span>';

        // Hover event popup
        echo '<div id="date_popup_'.$currentDate.'" class="date_popup_wrap none">';
        echo '<div class="date_window">';
        echo '<div class="popup_event">Events ('.$eventNum.')</div>';
        // For Add Event
        echo '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="pass(\''.$currentDate.'\');">check The day</a>';
        echo '</div></div>';

        echo '</li>';
        $dayCount++;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: this is not the whole code. from this codes it creates a calendar. and when you click a day it will create a pop up and you can click pass href . i have created to pop up a model box when clicking pass. but i cannot get data from mysql table because the date is pass as a javascript varable. and i dont knw ajax. can you help me on that

Comment: The question is very broad. Depending on the data amount you might be able to output all events into a javascript variable `var events = <?=json_encode($myDataAsArray)?>;` and load the data from there when you click, but you will probably need to use AJAX to fetch the data.

Comment: OK,thanks.. if anyone have a code for a event calendar please comment it..